# Is there a wider equal sign?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

I have defined the *equal by definition* sign:

[image]

with this code: `\newcommand{\eqdef}{\overset{def}{=}}`.

However, "def" extends over the edges of the equal sign. Is there a wider equal sign to use?

Comment: You could just use the various 'equivalence' signs (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Equivalent.html) that denote 'equality by definition'.

Comment: A more specific link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Defined.html

Comment: Rather than using an abbreviated word over an elongated equal sign, have you considered using either the `$\equiv$` symbol or the macro `$\overset{!}{=}$`?

Comment: I have considered $\equiv$, as well as $\triangleq$, but decided to use $\overset{def}{=}$, as (I think) is more obvious what it means

Comment: Related Question: [Short equals sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57378/short-equals-sign).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just put two equals signs, backing up slightly:

```
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=\joinrel=}}
```

This is how TeX builds extensible arrows.

[image]

The magic macro `\joinrel` is defined as

```
\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}
```

and the magic is done by the fact that TeX doesn't put spaces between consecutive relation symbols:

```
=\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}=
```

will thus result in two equals signs slightly superimposed to each other.

Comment: I had to accept this as, `\joinrel` > `\usepackage{extarrows}`.

Comment: Amazing solution, egreg! `:)`

Comment: @Zack On the other hand, the `\xlongequal` adapts to the text length

Answer (score 39):

The [`extarrows` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/extarrows) provides `\xlongequal{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{extarrows}% http://ctan.org/pkg/extarrows
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\xlongequal{\text{def}}}%
\begin{document}
\[ f(x) \eqdef g(x) = ax^2+bx+c \]
\end{document}
```

`extarrows` requires [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) (so it is loaded by default). As such, I've used  `\text` which scales to the appropriate text font in the given math size.

If you want the boundary of the overset `def` to be tighter, use

```
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\xlongequal{\!\text{def}\!}}%
```

which removes some space around `def`.

Answer (score 24):

If you want the size to math exactly, you can use `\resizebox` from [the `graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) and scale the width to the desired size (width of the unscaled version), and leave the height to be the same as the height of the `=` sign. Here is a comparison of the regular, and re sized versions:

[image]

Note that the manual tweak of `\kern1.25pt` may need to be adjusted based on the font being used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% 
\usepackage{graphicx}% needed for \resizebox
\usepackage{calc}%     needed for the width/height calculations

\newcommand*{\MyDef}{\mathrm{def}}
\newcommand*{\MyEqdefU}{\ensuremath{\mathrel{\overset{\MyDef}{=}}}}% Unscaled version
\newcommand*{\MyEqdef}{\mathrel{\overset{\MyDef}{\resizebox{\widthof{\kern1.25pt\MyEqdefU}}{\heightof{$=$}}{$=$}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    f(x) &\MyEqdefU g(x) = h(x) \quad\text{Unscaled}\\
    f(x) &\MyEqdef  g(x) = h(x) \quad\text{Scaled}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: a simply `\height` instead of `\heightof{=}` should also work, because you can take the natural height.

Comment: In the second version "def" slightly extends to the left beyond the equality symbol, at least in your output. Is it possible to improve?

Comment: @AlbertNash: I think that slight difference is due to how the font is designed. If you apply a _slight_ `\kern` as `\newcommand*{\eqdef}{\mathop{\overset{\MyDef}{\resizebox{\widthof{\kern1.25pt\eqdefU}}` then you should get better alignment (at least with the default font). [Here is the result of that](https://imgur.com/a/hleWtMB).

Comment: @AlbertNash: If the code does not compile for you there is probably some issue with your pacakges as I just ran it now to produce the linked result with TeXLive 2022. If you are not able to resolve the issue, I suggest you post a new question and include the list pf packages with version numbers are produced by `\listfiles` (just _before_ `\begin{document}`).

Comment: @PeterGrill it doesn't compile for me, it works fine with article.cls.

Comment: @user2478  replacing `\heightof{=}` by `\height` doesn't work in inline todonotes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks. I think I had an older `standalone` that was allowing to compile. Have now switched it to `article` class.

Comment: @AlbertNash: Have incorportaed the tweak mentioned in the comments to get a better match of the width and renamed the macros so as to not conflict with unicode-math.

Comment: @AlbertNash: Good point. Now using `\mathrel`.

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't strictly answer the question but if you only want the "def" to be about the same size as the equal sign you could also resize the text, i.e.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\def\Tiny{\fontsize{4pt}{4pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\eqdef}{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathclap{\text{\Tiny def}}}{=}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align} 
 A &\eqdef B \\
 &= C
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This way it looks better (in my opinion) when used together with normal equal signs.
[image]

Comment: Can you choose font sizes below 5pt? When I run your example, I get the warning `Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <4> not available ... size <5> substituted`.

Comment: @Mico: I don't really know. I chose the font size more or less randomly. But I guess your right and one really can't go below 5pt (at least not by default) as nothing changed when I tried smaller font sizes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one adaptation of the Philipp's proposition so as to take care of the different math modes.

```
% Source : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35404/is-there-a-wider-equal-sign

\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \makeatletter
        \newcommand{\@@eqDef}[1]{%
            \ensuremath{\overset{\mathclap{\text{\scalebox{#1}{def}}}}{=}}%
        }
        \newcommand*{\eqDef}{
            \mathchoice
                {% \displaystyle
                    \@@eqDef{0.7}
                }
                {% \textstyle
                    \@@eqDef{0.7}
                }
                {% \scriptstyle
                    \@@eqDef{0.6}
                }
                {% \scriptscriptstyle
                    \@@eqDef{0.5}
                }
        }
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    A &\eqDef B \\
    A &= C
\end{align}

\[
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \begin{array}{llll} 
        \textbf{Style}            & \verb!\eqDef!
        \\ \hline
        \verb!\displaystyle!      & \displaystyle      A \eqDef B
        \\
        \verb!\textstyle!         & \textstyle         A \eqDef B
        \\
        \verb!\scriptstyle!       & \scriptstyle       A \eqDef B
        \\
        \verb!\scriptscriptstyle! & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqDef B
    \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just the plain horizontal extension of the equation mark is possible with the graphicx package:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
 ...
{\scalebox{3}[1]{=}}
```

You can also define a command for this and use it lateron

```
\newcommand{\longeq}{\scalebox{3}[1]{=}}
```

like this:

```
\longeq
```

Comment: Will this provide the correct spacing around the relation? Perhaps wrap it with `\mathrel`. How would you replicate the output requested by the OP?