# Macro with an array and a customisable number of columns (from 2 to 5)

Tags: macros, arrays

I would like to automate the use of the following arrays. In the first one, the only arguments which change are `\verb!\eqDef!`, the commands tested, and `A \eqDef B`, the visual test.

**My problem is that I would like one solution which also allows to use 1, 2, 3 or 4 commands tested ?** In the second array, the commands tested are `\verb!\eqDef!`, `\verb!\eqTest!`, `\verb!\eqVerif!` and `\verb!\eqId!`, and the visual tests are `A \eqDef B`, `A \eqTest B`, `A \eqVerif B` and `A \eqId B`.

I give one file with the commands proposed in my examples.

### One command tested --> Two columns

```
\[
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \begin{array}{llll} 
        \textbf{Style}            & \verb!\eqDef!
        \\ \hline
        \verb!\displaystyle!      & \displaystyle      A \eqDef B
        \\
        \verb!\textstyle!         & \textstyle         A \eqDef B
        \\
        \verb!\scriptstyle!       & \scriptstyle       A \eqDef B
        \\
        \verb!\scriptscriptstyle! & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqDef B
    \end{array}
\]
```

### Four commands tested --> Five columns

```
\[
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \begin{array}{lllll} 
        \textbf{Style}
        & \verb!\eqDef!                   & \verb!\eqTest!
        & \verb!\eqVerif!                 & \verb!\eqId!
        \\ \hline
        \verb!\displaystyle!
        & \displaystyle      A \eqDef B   & \displaystyle      A \eqTest B
        & \displaystyle      A \eqVerif B & \displaystyle      A \eqId B
        \\
        \verb!\textstyle!
        & \textstyle         A \eqDef B   & \textstyle         A \eqTest B
        & \textstyle         A \eqVerif B & \textstyle         A \eqId B
        \\
        \verb!\scriptstyle!
        & \scriptstyle       A \eqDef B   & \scriptstyle       A \eqTest B
        & \scriptstyle       A \eqVerif B & \scriptstyle       A \eqId B
        \\
        \verb!\scriptscriptstyle!
        & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqDef B   & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqTest B
        & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqVerif B & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqId B
    \end{array}
\]
```

### One functionnal code

```
% Source : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35404/is-there-a-wider-equal-sign

\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \makeatletter
        \newcommand{\@@eqLikeDef}[3]{%
            \ensuremath{\overset{\mathclap{\text{\scalebox{#1}{#2}}}}{#3}}%
        }
        \newcommand*{\@eqLikeDef}[2]{
            \mathchoice
                {% \displaystyle
                    \@@eqLikeDef{0.7}{#1}{#2}
                }
                {% \textstyle
                    \@@eqLikeDef{0.7}{#1}{#2}
                }
                {% \scriptstyle
                    \@@eqLikeDef{0.6}{#1}{#2}
                }
                {% \scriptscriptstyle
                    \@@eqLikeDef{0.5}{#1}{#2}
                }
        }

        \newcommand*{\eqDef}{\@eqLikeDef{Def}{=}}
        \newcommand*{\eqTest}{\@eqLikeDef{Test}{=}}
        \newcommand*{\eqVerif}{\@eqLikeDef{?}{=}}
        \newcommand*{\eqId}{\@eqLikeDef{Id}{=}}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Equality Signs}

\[
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \begin{array}{lllll} 
        \textbf{Style}
        & \verb!\eqDef!                   & \verb!\eqTest!
        & \verb!\eqVerif!                 & \verb!\eqId!
        \\ \hline
        \verb!\displaystyle!
        & \displaystyle      A \eqDef B   & \displaystyle      A \eqTest B
        & \displaystyle      A \eqVerif B & \displaystyle      A \eqId B
        \\
        \verb!\textstyle!
        & \textstyle         A \eqDef B   & \textstyle         A \eqTest B
        & \textstyle         A \eqVerif B & \textstyle         A \eqId B
        \\
        \verb!\scriptstyle!
        & \scriptstyle       A \eqDef B   & \scriptstyle       A \eqTest B
        & \scriptstyle       A \eqVerif B & \scriptstyle       A \eqId B
        \\
        \verb!\scriptscriptstyle!
        & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqDef B   & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqTest B
        & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqVerif B & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqId B
    \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I fully understand what is required.

### Choose Columns:

If you mean that you want to use the same table data, and selectively choose which columns to print then one way of doing that is to use the `collcell` package which allows the contents of the table to be passed to a macro. Using this I have defined a macro that takes the data entry and returns an empty string when the `S` column type is used:

```
\newcommand*{\SupressEntry}[1]{}%
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\collectcell\SupressEntry}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}%
```

So, if you want the column printed use the usual `l`, but if you don't want it printed use `L`.  Here is the output using the `\begin{array}{l l l l l}`:

[image]

and same table with `\begin{array}{l l S l S}` (i.e., suppress columns 3 and 5):
[image]

### Choose Rows:

If you question is about selecting rows, there are many ways to do that. One way is to use `newtoggle` from the `etoolbox` package.  For example `\newtoggle{ShowDisplayStyle}`. Then when you want to enable this row, just set `\toggletrue{ShowDisplayStyle}` to show this row, but if you want this row suppressed `\togglefalse{ShowDisplayStyle}`.

Here is the outout with `\togglefalse{ShowTextStyle}` and `\togglefalse{ShowScriptStyle}`:

[image]

### Reuse Table without Repeating Data:

I would also suggest wrapping the data into a macro as I have below with the `\TableData` macro to make it less error prone.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{collcell}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \newcommand*{\SupressEntry}[1]{}%
    \newcolumntype{S}{>{\collectcell\SupressEntry}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}%

    \newtoggle{ShowDisplayStyle}
    \newtoggle{ShowTextStyle}
    \newtoggle{ShowScriptStyle}
    \newtoggle{ShowScriptScriptStyle}

    % Chose which ones are printed:
    \toggletrue{ShowDisplayStyle}
    \toggletrue{ShowTextStyle}
    \toggletrue{ShowScriptStyle}
    \toggletrue{ShowScriptScriptStyle}


    \makeatletter
        \newcommand{\@@eqLikeDef}[3]{%
            \ensuremath{\overset{\mathclap{\text{\scalebox{#1}{#2}}}}{#3}}%
        }
        \newcommand*{\@eqLikeDef}[2]{
            \mathchoice
                {% \displaystyle
                    \@@eqLikeDef{0.7}{#1}{#2}
                }
                {% \textstyle
                    \@@eqLikeDef{0.7}{#1}{#2}
                }
                {% \scriptstyle
                    \@@eqLikeDef{0.6}{#1}{#2}
                }
                {% \scriptscriptstyle
                    \@@eqLikeDef{0.5}{#1}{#2}
                }
        }

        \newcommand*{\eqDef}{\@eqLikeDef{Def}{=}}
        \newcommand*{\eqTest}{\@eqLikeDef{Test}{=}}
        \newcommand*{\eqVerif}{\@eqLikeDef{?}{=}}
        \newcommand*{\eqId}{\@eqLikeDef{Id}{=}}
    \makeatother

\newcommand{\Label}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}%
\newcommand{\TableData}{%
        \textbf{Style}
        & \Label{eqDef}                   & \Label{eqTest}
        & \Label{eqVerif}                 & \Label{eqId}
        \\ \hline
    \iftoggle{ShowDisplayStyle}{
        \Label{displaystyle}
        & \displaystyle      A \eqDef B   & \displaystyle      A \eqTest B
        & \displaystyle      A \eqVerif B & \displaystyle      A \eqId B
        \\
    }{}
    \iftoggle{ShowTextStyle}{
        \Label{textstyle}
        & \textstyle         A \eqDef B   & \textstyle         A \eqTest B
        & \textstyle         A \eqVerif B & \textstyle         A \eqId B
        \\
    }{}
    \iftoggle{ShowScriptStyle}{
        \Label{scriptstyle}
        & \scriptstyle       A \eqDef B   & \scriptstyle       A \eqTest B
        & \scriptstyle       A \eqVerif B & \scriptstyle       A \eqId B
        \\
     }{}
     \iftoggle{ShowScriptScriptStyle}{
       \Label{scriptscriptstyle}
        & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqDef B   & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqTest B
        & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqVerif B & \scriptscriptstyle A \eqId B
        \\
     }{}
}
\begin{document}

\section{Equality Signs: All Styles and Commands}
\[
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \begin{array}{l l l l l} 
        \TableData
    \end{array}
\]

\section{Equality Signs: Only Columns 3 and 5}
\[
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \begin{array}{l l S l S} 
        \TableData
    \end{array}
\]

\section{Equality Signs:Only textstyle and scriptstyle Commands}
    \togglefalse{ShowTextStyle}
    \togglefalse{ShowScriptStyle}
\[
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \begin{array}{l l l l l} 
        \TableData
    \end{array}
\]
    \toggletrue{ShowTextStyle}
    \toggletrue{ShowScriptStyle}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may also use @ egreg's answer or @ MartinScharrer's comment in [Easiest way to delete a column?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/easiest-way-to-delete-a-column/16607#16607) that does not require the [`collcell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) - that is, LaTeX provides boxing capability by default. Regardless, I like your approach to keep the entire structure and filter columns.

Comment: @Peter Grill: thanks. Indeed, I would like to have the possibilty to change what I've called arguments in my question. I'll adapt your proposition to do one command with one to four arguments which are each couples of arguments (nameOfTheCommand, textUsedForTest). It would not be hard.