# How can I have "long ="

Tags: symbols

In my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763604/prove-that-if-a-b-and-c-are-sets-then-a-b-cup-a-c-a-b-ca/1763840#1763840).
 - How can I have "*long =*" so that the length of the word "de morgan" is equal the length of "="?
Thank you.

Comment: If this specifically deals with MathJax, then we can't help you here, as MathJax uses a limited set of (La)TeX-related functionality. If this is about pure (La)TeX, then we can help!

Comment: Although I want it for MathJax for now, But If the question has an answer  for (La)TeX, some day one may use it; maybe me, maybe others.

Comment: Alternative duplicate: [Is there a wider equal sign?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35404/5764)