# long equality symbol for DVI output

Tags: math-fonts, dvi, scalebox

Continuing [A better long ≝ (defining equals, equals to by definition) without bumps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674648/a-better-long-%e2%89%9d-defining-equals-equals-to-by-definition-without-bumps#comment1676057_674648), feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\longEquals}{\mathrel{\scalebox{2}[1]{=}}}% Thanks to Marjin!
\begin{document}
\( = A \longEquals\)
\end{document}
```

to `latex` yields

[image: output]

in the DVI viewer `xdvi`.  Both equality symbols come out equal, but the second equality should be twice as long.  (Running the DVI output through dvips produces a long equality symbol as expected, though.)  Any better long equality symbol that also shows up natively in the DVI?

Comment: `\scalebox` achieves its effect using postscript commands that your DVI viewer probably does not evaluate. If you convert the dvi to ps (`dvips`) and view the ps file with a ps viewer, the length should have increased. If you intend to print the document, you will have to convert it to ps or pdf anyway. What prevents you from using `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`?

Comment: @gernot Yes, of course. I hope that some font has a native long “=” so that we don't have to refer to PostScript commands. As for using all the other compilers, I do use them, too. Sometimes, I prefer to take a look at the DVI output for debugging purposes, and in this case, I prefer that most of my output looks as it should look without distracting me by small issues (such as the one in this post).

Comment: Have you checked https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35406/110998?

Comment: @gernot `=\joinrel=` leads to a bump in the middle at low resolutions; cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674648 .